# Conventional command line tool OSX save data location

Tags: macos, unix, backup, command-line-interface

Im making a command line tool for Mac that does some work on .strings files. Part of the process is making a backup of the .strings files it will operate on so that, in case something gets messed up, the user's files will still be safe somewhere for retrieval.

What directory is in your opinion best to save such data? I'm assuming a temp directory of sorts but not sure where that should be. If this was an application in the macOS sense, i could store this data in the application folder. However this is a command line tool which will be added in /usr/local/bin, following the UNIX way of doing things, and it would feel "wrong" to put that data in there.

Comment: Why not in the original location of the strings file, with .strings.bak extension? Even if by some reason your script can't restore the .bak, the user can easily find it and manually rename it.

Comment: thats the idea im currently going with but some people have complained that it "junks up" their project ( as the original files are found within their projects )

its not a bad idea and is my fallback scenario but i was thinking something less visible as normally the backup shouldnt be needed unless my code messes something up somehow

Comment: Do a sanity check at the end, and delete the backup. Add to the documentation, that they may add *.strings.bak to .gitignore, svn:global-ignores or similar. 
For sure I will want the backup in my project folder if something goes wrong, I will hate to need to remember where to search for it, and copy it from there. So, you can't make everyone happy :)

Comment: Hmm ok. However what if it was a cache file in another example of a cli tool that needed to be stored globally. Where would i need to store that ideally?